# How can I modify init script to make it start after delay or event?

Tags: initialization, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, supervisord, upstart

I use supervisor.
I have configuration file that launches a task in a directory that is mounted after some time after system startup (`/vagrant/task.sh`).

So when system starts, supervisor can't start. I have to run `sudo service supervisor start` command after the system is loaded and the `/vagrant` directory is mounted.

How can I add delay to `/etc/init.d/supervisor` to make it start after delay or event?

Comment: Are you tried to use the command `sleep NUMBER[SUFFIX]` in your task.sh?

Comment: @T.C. I can't because the file with command doesn't exist at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution (event `vagrant-mounted`):

```
cat << EOF > /etc/init/supervisor-launcher.conf
description "Supervisor Launcher"
start on vagrant-mounted
script
  /usr/sbin/service supervisor start
end script
EOF
```